# selecting multiple instances with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery statement :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#toggle-link').click(function(){
$(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
 $('#box-to-toggle').toggle();

});
});
```

I have several instances of the #box-to-toggle so when i click on the #toogle-link link every instance of the box opens and closes. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this so the link only opens the box in the same div. here is the html structure.

```
<div id='holder'>
    <div id='toggle-link'>+</div>
    <div id='box-to-toggle'>
        <!-- hide / show content here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id='holder'>
    <div id='toggle-link'>+</div>
    <div id='box-to-toggle'>
        <!-- hide / show content here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id='holder'>
    <div id='toggle-link'>+</div>
    <div id='box-to-toggle'>
        <!-- hide / show content here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id='holder'>
    <div id='toggle-link'>+</div>
    <div id='box-to-toggle'>
        <!-- hide / show content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreceatied

Comment: Use this it will give reference to only which is clicked .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple id's are bad for your health, so change those into classNames. And then:

```
$(this).parent().find(".box-to-toggle").toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

See in your markup there are some ids which are instanced to multiple elements in a single page. There are multiple `#holder, #toggle-link` and `#box-to-toggle`.

This would be better if you change your *id* notation to *class*, so your markup should now change id to class:

```
<div class='holder'>
   <div class='toggle-link'>+</div>
   <div class='box-to-toggle'>
       <!-- hide / show content here -->
   </div>
</div>
.....more divs......
```

and jQuery is fine just one change, don't toggle the div with class name instead you can use `.next(), .siblings()`:

#### with `.next()`:

```
$('.toggle-link').click(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.text($this.text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
   $this.next('.box-to-toggle').toggle();
});
```

#### with `.siblings()`:

```
$('.toggle-link').click(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.text($this.text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
   $this.siblings('.box-to-toggle').toggle();
});
```

and `#` id notation change to `.` class notation.

Answer (score 1):

As all the answers suggest, go for unique `id` always and use `class` in place of `id` for the current question you have asked:

```
$('.toggle-link').click(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
    $(this).next("div.box-to-toggle").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it work would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle-link').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .text($this.text() == '+' ? '-' : '+')
            .siblings('#box-to-toggle').toggle();
    });
});
```

BTW. I don't think it's a good idea for multiple elements to share the same id. Using a class would be more logical to me.